# Wrong translation "you sure you want to send order email to customer?". Where is it?

Tags: email, magento, translation, backend

I found an error with the Italian translation the phrase "Are you sure you want to send order email to customer?" (in the Backend -> Order).
I would like to correct it but I don't found the file with the phrase!
I checked the file "Mage_Sales.csv" (and all the .csv!) and in the Translation inline but it there is not!
Where could it be? In the database??
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This phrase *is* contained in `Mage_Sales.csv`. However, it could be overridden by

1. A theme translation. Check `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/locale/it_IT/translate.csv` or if you have a custom admin theme, look there instead of `default/default`.
2. An inline translation. These are stored in the database table `core_translate`

Comment: Great! It was in the table core_translate! Thanks